# I lost power during an upgrade to Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, power-management

During a recent attempt to upgrade to the newest upgrade for Ubuntu (16.something something) I lost power.  Now when I turn on my computer, it starts to boot then pages of code start flashing across the screen so fast that the only thing I can read is "orphaned" . Can I just do a clean install?  I'm not worried about losing anything,  since I had just backed everything up a few minutes before I started the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a clean install would work here and nicely since you properly backed everything up. Although additoinal programs might not be backed up so you might need to install other packages you installed after installatoin.  I would need more than the vague discription of orphaned to try and rescue that system.

Comment: reinstalling is going to be best. you could mount the broken system's hard drive and check the list of installed packages if you want to check which packages you had and where they came from, see /var/lib/apt/extended_states (http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me on one of the upgrades that I did. Unlike you though I had not backed up my data and therefore lost it all. I had to do a clean install to get my system to boot up. Next time though, make sure your power is connected all OK.